# JS / Chrome Extension - EventListener & Mutation do not detect changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-listener

I am building a chrome extension and need to call a function once changes on the site have been detected. Preferably, I want to keep an eye on changes happening in an `<iframe>`, but since I cant get it to work I am already happy to fire the code whenever any change is detected.

this is the code in my inject.js file:

```
// run script when site changes are detected
chrome.storage.local.get("obj", function (res) {
    console.log("setting page data object from listener:");
    console.log(res);

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        findKeyword();
        console.log("Listener onUpdate Executed");
    });

    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        findKeyword();
        console.log("Listener onActivated Executed");
    });

    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {         
       findKeyword();
       console.log("Listener onCreated Executed");

    });


    // iFrame Listeners    
    var iframe_id = res.obj.iframe_id;
    //var iframe = document.getElementById(res.obj.iframe_id);      // alternative

    $(iframe_id).find("body").on('mouseup', function(event) {
        findKeyword();
        console.log("iFrame Listener - MouseUp");
    });

    $('iframe#com.ihg.crm.web.hotel.Hotel').load(function() {
      findKeyword();
      alert("iFrame Listener - Load");
    });

    iframe_id.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('change', function() {
        findKeyword();
        console.log("iFrame Listener - body changes");
    });


    // MutationObservers
    var dom_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
        findKeyword();
        console.log('Mutation observed');
    });

});
```

In addition, I am recently getting a `Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined` error, which is weird as I am firing the code from my background script, which AFAIK only loads once all content has loaded.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: 1) Content scripts [can't use](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) chrome.tabs API so you'll need to rework your code. 2) to observe inside iframes directly those have to be same-origin, otherwise you need to run a content script inside the iframe using `"all_frames":true` in manifest.json or `allFrames:true` in chrome.tabs.executeScript, see the documentation, 3) You didn't start your MutationObserver via its observe() method. 4) Background script runs in a separate hidden background page not related to content scripts in any capacity.

Comment: regarding #1, what are my options? How can I get my code executed with event listeners / MutationObservers?

Comment: The most important step is to make sure you understand the extension architecture, then everything would be absolutely trivial and self-evident. The content script runs in every web page and can access DOM stuff like MutationObserver. The background script runs in a separate background page and can use all of the permitted chrome.* API.

Comment: The problem is that even when placing the code in my background.js, it still doesnt work... Other eventlisteners (eg. button click) work well in the content.js

Comment: I'm bad at explaining obviously. You still misunderstand the difference between the content scripts and background scripts.